# Composer dump-autoload error when a vendor is in a package konekt/concord

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package, laravel-artisan

the composer throws error on root folder:

> Class 'Konekt\Concord\BaseBoxServiceProvider' not found
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event
> returned with error code 255

While if I trying it in the package then the class is found. The files are the next:

```
namespace Ecommerce\Shop\Providers;
use Konekt\Concord\BaseBoxServiceProvider;
class ShopServiceProvider extends BaseBoxServiceProvider{
```

and this class isn't found anymore:

```
namespace Konekt\Concord;
abstract class BaseBoxServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider{
```

The vendor of it and the Src are in packages/ecommerce/shop (/vendor or /src).
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Perhaps run `composer install / update`?

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Looks like the package you're using doesn't handle Laravel autodiscover. You may have to register it manually by adding the ServiceProvider in your config/app.php file. Try adding `Konekt\Concord\BaseBoxServiceProvider::class,` to the providers array.

Comment: composer install/update done, with the same error and it is already in providers array, but nothing :(

Comment: Hey, the author of the Concord package here. If you still have this error, could you please tell me what is the output of this command: `composer show konekt/concord|grep versions` ?